# idb-companion: command not found after installing via homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have installed idb-companion in line with the instructions in their [docs](https://github.com/facebook/idb#quick-start), but when I run `idb list-targets` I get `idb: command not found`. `idb-companion` shows up when I `brew list`. I also tried installing and running the universal `.tar.gz` folder from their latest [release](https://github.com/facebook/idb/releases), but got no where. Although I only ran that via the Finder GUI, because I wasn't sure how to execute that from the CLI.

I understand there is some homebrew path I may have to change. I have actually had homebrew issues before and so have usually resorted to installing everything via node where possible. In this case it's not, so I tried the `.tar.gz` file.

How can I get `idb-companion` to start working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is the case, your python path is not set. You need to set your python path. Faced the same issue was resolved with setting python path.

Answer (score 0):

first install it

```
brew tap facebook/fb
brew install idb-companion
```

then check /usr/local/bin/idb-companion, simple run it in terminal
if not exist, create a link:

```
ln -s (pathto)/idb-companion /usr/local/bin/idb-companion
```

Answer (score 0):

To run the command line you must install the python package.
Please note that if you install the python package in a virtual environment you must activate the environment before running the command:

1. Open terminal
2. Activate virtual environment:
   `source <path to your virtual env>/bin/activate` [this step is optional]
3. Run the following commands:

```
pip install fb-idb
idb list-targets
```

Answer (score -1):

```
which idb
```

this command gives your idb path